# WF 4.0 Resources Collection

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

Though WF 4.0 beta1 released, we dont have much resources available on the net to understand the concepts.. i know lot of bloggers are keep putting some materials about WF 4.0. it would be great if we share all the resources here..

From my side,

Linked list all WF 4.0 Collection...

```
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WF/WF4Services.aspx
http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/default.aspx
http://bloggersguides.net/media/p/188.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/endpoint/default.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/rjacobs/default.aspx
http://www.theworkflowelement.com/
http://blogs.msdn.com/mwinkle/default.aspx
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the main ones, that I check at least, and I haven't seem much else. I expect things to heat up a little with the Dublin CTP.

Matt Milner over at PluralSight has some posts that are worth checking out.

http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/tags/Windows+Workflow+Foundation/default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here is another site where some videos on WF 4.0 are posted:

http://www.cloudcasts.net/Default.aspx?category=WCF%20WF%204.0

Answer (score 0):

```
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=35ec8682-d5fd-4bc3-a51a-d8ad115a8792
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd851337.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee342461.aspx
http://channel9.msdn.com/tags/endpoint%20.NET%204/
```